# Describe the maximal ideals in the ring of Gaussian Integers $\Bbb Z[i]$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory

Describe the maximal ideals in the ring of Gaussian Integers $\Bbb Z[i]$.

So first of all my question would be - Is it possible to write any ideal of $\Bbb Z[i]$ (which happens to be a PID) as $\langle a\rangle$ or does it have to be $\langle a + bi\rangle$ or are they the same thing?

i.e Can **ANY** Ideal in $Z[i]$ be written as $\langle a\rangle$ ?

Further, I am not able to continue. Please help!

Some possible references (I looked through these but to no avail):

1. [Maximal ideals in the ring of Gaussian integers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/591573/maximal-ideals-in-the-ring-of-gaussian-integers)
2. [How to find all the maximal ideals of $\mathbb Z_n?$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/366119/how-to-find-all-the-maximal-ideals-of-mathbb-z-n)
3. [Ideals in the ring of Gaussian integers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/443842/ideals-in-the-ring-of-gaussian-integers)

Comment: Use the definition of PID. and an Ideal

Comment: @Kumar Could not conclude anything substantial from the above link.

Comment: What do you denote $a$ in $\langle a\rangle$? An ordinary integer or a Gauß integer?

Comment: I think if you look at the question and answer of the link, you would be able to get the answer. Anyways. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/764437/the-gaussian-integers-are-isomorphic-to-mathbbzx-x21?noredirect=1&lq=1 This link will help you to understand more if you understand polynomial rings. I would also recommend you to have a look at **Dummit and Foote, Abstract Algebra**. Happy idealizing. :P

Comment: Well, $\;\Bbb Z[i]\;$ is an Euclidean domain and is thus a PID, so yes: every ideal in the ring can be written as $\;\langle a\rangle\;$ ...as long as $\;a=x+iy\,,\,\,x,y\in\Bbb Z\;$ .

Comment: The maximal ideals of $\Bbb{Z}[i]$ are those generated by the primes of this ring. Whether a rational (=usual) prime $p$ remains a prime in $\Bbb{Z}[i]$ depends on its residue class modulo $4$. If $p\not\equiv-1\pmod4$, then it factors further.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since  $\mathbf Z[i]$ is a P.I.D. – actually a Euclidean domain with the norm: $N(a+bi)=a^2+b^2$ as a Euclidean function, maximal ideals  are generated by *irreducible* elements.

Also $a+bi$ is irreducible if $N(a+bi)$ is prime, because the norm is multiplicative, i.e. $$N\bigl((a+bi)(c+di)\bigr)=N(a+bi)N(c+di).$$

Answer (score 6):

No; not every ideal of $\Bbb{Z}[i]$ is of the form $\langle a\rangle$ for some integer $a$. A simple example is the ideal $\langle 1+i\rangle$. It contains the integer $2=(1+i)(1-i)$, so if it is generated by an integer, then it must be generated by a divisor of $2$. But then it should equal either $\langle1\rangle=\Bbb{Z}[i]$ or $\langle2\rangle$, which it doesn't.

Comment: Makes sense. So then how do I continue now?